# Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned message in Magento 2

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento-2.0.5

I am using Magento 2.0.5. When I run the `composer update` or `composer install` command it's showing the following warning.

> Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
>   Use friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.

[image]

I read https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers/issues/46 but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 12):

As the existing answers are not quite clear about it:

1. this is not an error, only a warning. The abandoned package still exists, and Magento already replaced the dependency somewhere in version 2.1 so you don't have to worry about it.
2. There seem to be cases where the warning prevents further installations. In that case, or if you want to get rid of the warning and use the current version of phpcsfixer (which is a dev tool and not required for Magento to operate), run these commands in your project root:

   ```
   composer remove fabpot/php-cs-fixer
   composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
   ```

   Do not edit `composer.json` or even `composer.lock` directly to avoid conflicts!

Answer (score 3):

It's a dependency in magento2 as it says there. They will change it soon. Magento uses that dependency so I don't think you can do anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this same issue while installing Magento 2.1.8 using Composer.

This is only a warning, not an error. So, you can either ignore it or get rid of this warning by replacing the abandoned package with the required version of phpcsfixer in your Magento installation.

To fix this warning, run the following commands in your project root:

```
composer remove fabpot/php-cs-fixer
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer 2.1.1
```

**Note:** This is a known issue [#7310](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7310) and Magento already updated this dependency in the next major release Magento 2.2.

And one more thing, please do not edit `composer.json` or `composer.lock` file directly. It may create conflict when you upgrade the Magento in future.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Same with me from Magento 2.0.7 to 2.1.0, after installing patch MDVA-532 ( i am using php 5.6.20 ). Upgrade interrupted with the above message. Now nothing is working.

To fix this issue you need to do change in composer.json > "require-dev" the line:

```
-"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2"
```

with

```
 -"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.0".
```

This removed fabpot/php-cs-fixer and installed friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer.

But upgrade also interrupted.

Comment: Magento will change it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve that through updating the composer.json file by replacing

```
"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2"
```

with

```
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.0"
```

and on the composer.lock  replacing

```
"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "0.4.0"
```

with

```
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "0.4.0"
```

and replacing

```
"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "1.7.*"
```

with

```
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "2.0.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue as well. But now I have resolved it already.

Replace `"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2"` with `-"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.0"` both in `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file. Everything goes OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The problem was that I replaced fabpot/php-cs-fixer with friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer without replacing it in composer.lock as well. I ran

```
composer self-update
composer clear-cache
```

However, each time I tried to execute "composer update" it hung at updating dependencies. You can see this by running

```
composer update -vvv
```

So, at last, I rolled back the changes made to require-dev in composer.json and all went well updating Magento version to 2.1.10

Then, I decided to

```
composer remove fabpot/php-cs-fixer
```

And then

```
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

However, installation fails because the symfony/console version requirements of friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v.2.8 require PHP 7.1. That's the problem, because, Magento 2.1 does not support this version of php. **Therefore, friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer can only be installed with Magento 2.2**

Answer (score -2):

It is fixed like this for my case.

1. First run as administrator.
2. Next, run composer install command in Node.js command prompt.