# fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, magento2.1.6

I'm trying to install magento data migration tool for magento 2.1.6, while on ssh session, i get an error message saying: `Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friends ofphp/php-cs-fixer instead`
following the advice on that [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120754/package-fabpot-php-cs-fixer-is-abandoned-message-in-magento-2)

I tried changing the  `"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2"` with `"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.0"` on the composer.json rerun, but the problem appeared once again. I tried to edit the json.lock, but it doesn't have `"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2"`

just "`fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "0.4.0"` and `"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "1.7.*"`

any advice how to proceed?

Comment: I know, you already linked that question, but it's the same problem - you might want to add your answer there.

Comment: i asked the question there too, but it was deleted, i guess i shouldn't post "me too" questions

Comment: That's right, but now that you have an answer, feel free to add it there. If it is an addition to an existing answer, you can also add a comment instead.

Comment: i can't comment yet, i've under 50 reputation.  about your post there, the migration tool won't be installed because of that warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve that through updating the composer.jason file by replacing

```
"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2"
```

with

```
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.0"
```

and on the composer.lock  replacing

```
"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "0.4.0"
```

with

```
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "0.4.0"
```

and replacing

```
"fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "1.7.*"
```

with

```
"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "2.0.*"
```